# Bibtex not compiling correctly

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, bibliographies

I have the following bibliography entry:

```
@proceedings{ANA94,
title = {A methodology for automatic term recognition},
author = {Sophia Ananiadou},
booktitle = {Proceedings of the 15th conference on Computational linguistics},
volume = {2},
publisher = {Association for Computational Linguistics},
year = {1994}
}
```

When I compile I get the following warning:

> ```
> Warning--to sort, need editor or key in ANA94
> ```

For some reason all proceedings entries are using editors for reference, I need to use authors as the point of reference.

Comment: This entry is not a `@proceedings`, it is an `@inproceeedings`. `@proceedings` is for the entire book (which in this case normally does not have an author - only an editor), `@inproceedings` for an article within such a book (which has an author).

Comment: Please consider showing a full [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) this may very well depend on the bibliography package and style you use. I suspect you are not using `biblatex` contrary to your tag, but I would like to be sure.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Your entry is an `@inproceedings` entry

```
@inproceedings{ANA94,
  title     = {A methodology for automatic term recognition},
  author    = {Sophia Ananiadou},
  booktitle = {Proceedings of the 15th conference on Computational linguistics},
  volume    = {2},
  publisher = {Association for Computational Linguistics},
  year      = {1994},
}
```

A `@proceedings` is for the entire conference proceedings volume and it will normally have an editor. An `@inproceedings`, however, is for a specific article/chapter in a conference value and will be primarily associated with the `author`.